# Replace value of object property in multiple JSON files

Tags: json, powershell, file, jq

I'm working with multiple JSON files that are located in the same folder.

Files contain objects with the same properties and they are such as:

```json
{  
    "identifier": "cameraA",
    "alias": "a",
    "rtsp": "192.168.1.1"
}
```

I want to replace a property for all the objects in the JSON files at the same time for a certain condition.

For example, let's say that I want to replace all the rtsp values of the objects with identifier equal to "cameraA".

I've been trying with something like:

```
 jq 'if .identifier == \"cameraA" then .rtsp=\"cameraX" else . end' -c *.json
```

But it isn't working.

Is there a simple way to replace the property of an object among multiple JSON files?

Comment: Get rid of those unnecessary slashes \ ? What is not working otherwise?

Comment: Without slashes is not working at all using the Windows Powershell...

Comment: It wasn't part of the original post, that its being tested in Powershell. So what is not working

Comment: Yes, right, I fogot to mention it. I'm not sure why isn't working: I guess is the last part of the line (*.json), I don't know how to point to mutiple files using the jq command. Also I'm not quite sure if it's possible to replace text directly in file using jq. Maybe it would be easier to use another command, rather than jq... I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

jq can only write to STDIN and STDOUT, so the simplest approach would be to process one file at a time, e.g. putting your jq program inside a shell loop.  [sponge](/questions/tagged/sponge) is often used when employing this approach.

However, there is an alternative that has the advantage of efficiency.  It requires only one invocation of jq, the output of which would include the filename information (obtained from `input_filename`).  This output would then be the input of an auxiliary process, e.g. `awk`.